# Performing Cost Path analysis in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, spatial-analyst, cost-path

Is it possible to model the easiest pathway through a landscape between many points (rather than just two)?

I want to carry out a cost-path analysis,  I would like to display the easiest pathways through the entire study region (not just one route but all)- by taking into account slope and proximity of sites to rivers or valley floors.

I have a DEM raster (obtained from UK ordnance survey - Landform-panorama). River systems were in the form of a polygon shapefile, which I have converted in to a raster layer. The lat/lon coordinates of the 10 sites where added to the DEM raster as a feature class.

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

Answer (score 8):

In order to perform this task in ArcGIS 10.1, you will require the **[Spatial Analyst Extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_the_ArcGIS_Spatial_Analyst_extension/005900000001000000/)** which can perform analysis on rasters including Least-Cost Path.

ESRI has created a **[series of tutorials](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_the_ArcGIS_Spatial_Analyst_extension_Tutorial/00nt00000002000000/)** to get you started with Spatial Analyst.  The [**last of which**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_4_Finding_an_alternate_access_route/00nt00000005000000/) creates the optimal route to a site.  If you follow the tutorial you should be on your way to finding the optimal route for all ten of your sites.  The results will look something like this:

[image]

It sounds as if the rasters you're missing are the slope raster as well as the distance rasters to rivers and valley floors (wouldn't valley floors usually contain some sort of waterway?)  You should be able to easily create these with Spatial Analyst.

If you don't have access to Spatial Analyst, you should be able to create them and perform the analysis using open source GIS such as [**QGIS**](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) or [**GRASS**](http://grass.osgeo.org/).  The tools needed are available in those, and you could just adapt the tutorial for use in those programs.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I really appreciate it! I do have access to Spatial Analyst, and I think I know how to create the slope raster but I am not really sure how to create distance rasters to rivers and valley floors from the data I already have - which is a polygon shapefile of River systems that I have converted in to a raster layer. Can this be used to create distance rasters for both rivers and valley floors (given, as you pointed out, valley floors usually contain some sort of waterway)? And if so, how? As always any advice would be massively appreciated!

Comment: to carry out this analysis is it necessary to convert polygon to a raster or can it stay as a shapefile?

Comment: If you go through all four tutorials, you'll learn all the tools you need for this analysis.  Including the euclidean distance tool.  All of this analysis will be done using rasters.

Comment: I followed the steps using my own data, but at the end of the 3rd tutorial it would only display the results of the slope and not the rest (distance to rivers and sites). in the original question section  have included 2 images, the model steps and the output.

Comment: I can't see any the edits to your question.  Could you please try again?

Comment: I think I may have managed to create a suitable locations raster, but I am honestly not clear how to proceed to the next step. what I basically want to do is create a map displaying all pathways (least cost) there may be for the entire region. I don't have a origin and destination point and i don't want the map to display just one path. I don't really understand what i should do. I would be really appreciate any help!

Comment: If you have your suitable locations, are they your destinations?  You want to find the least cost to them?  From where?

Comment: that's exactly my problem, as the image above shows, there is a lot of green area indicating apparently suitable locations that specify the criteria - low slope, close to rivers. but i want to display the pathways - i don't have destination/origin points - i was wondering whether instead of just calculating the pathways between points, where there is a way to just get the program to display existing pathways (without inputting origin/destination points). I thought i could later add my sites and then see whether they actually lie along any of these pathways. is this possible?